# Images disappear when switching to 3.5 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have two images that I am showing in a UIImageView, they both show up fine when they are edited on the extended storyboard and when ran in the 4in simulator. However when I switch the storyboard to the shorter 4 & 4S size the images disappear, the UIImageViews are still there however it will not display the images. The first picture is of the 4in storyboard and the second is of the 3.5in, all I did was click the resize button at the bottom of the editor to shrink it.

[image: 5 & 5S storyboard]
[image: 3.5in storyboard]

Comment: Can you just post the code of the viewDidLoad function so that others can get some more clarity about your question?

Comment: Could you show us your code? Or screen of your result?

Comment: The only line of code in my viewDidLoad is a call to the super. I am adding pictures above to better illustrate what is happening.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout or struts and springs? Xcode 5 and Storyboards?

Comment: On my main.storyboard autolayout is disabled.

Comment: How do you add your images? Are you using Image Assets?

Comment: Yes I am using the Image.xcassets folder, just dragging them into it and adding an image for both the 1x and 2x. Then going to the UIImageView and selecting the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a simple layout issue in IB. If you have Autolayout disabled then you need to set some struts for each of the images so that they reposition when the screen size changes. On the right side of IB in Utilities open the Size Inspector panel and set up the Autosizing as in the image below.

Notice only one strut is red, this keeps the content pinned to the bottom.

[image]